# PHP: retrieving full path from a selected file to import data to database

Tags: php, mysql, file-io, pathname

I want to allow the user to select a file from which data is exported and saved into a database. I found the following code to import the data:

```
$fp = fopen("people.csv", "r");

while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
$char =  split("\t",$line,4); 
 list($name, $age,$height,$date) = $char;
//Split the line by the tab delimiter and store it in our list
$sql = "insert into people(name,age,height,date) values('$name','$age','$height','$date')"; // Generate our sql string
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // Execute the sql
//fclose($line);
```

I'm not sure if it works but i'm yet to get that far. My question is how do I get the full path name of the selected file so I can feed it into the following command rather than hard coding the filename:

```
$fp = fopen("people.csv", "r");
```

I have spent alot time researching this but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let users upload this file, you should implement file upload. Please check [W3Schools Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for instructions.

The main idea is to get file path from `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`:

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "r");
```

If you store your file statically in your web project folder, you can use the path including your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] + 'relative/path/to/your/file/' + 'people.csv';
```

Comment: Thanks for repsponding. If its possible I don't actually want to upload the file I just need the path of the file on the local machine.  Is there any other way or do I have to upload the file and use the pathname of the file on the server.

Comment: @batsta13 To process the file with PHP, you should have this file on a server where your PHP interpreter is installed. You can upload file another way, then you should use the second approach with `DOCUMENT_ROOT` I've mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the path of the current file via the `__DIR__` magic constant;

[Magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

In your case;

```
echo __DIR__ . 'people.csv';
```

Also, you may consider using the built-in CSV functions that PHP offers;
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

If you want to skip processing the file via PHP altogether, MySQL offers ways to directly import data from a CSV file;

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html